# How to find probability of the best choose?

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

One hundred candidates pretending for a position of a secretary are waiting for their personal interview with the head of the company. The interviewer has to tell them right away if they are suitable for the given position or not. The candidates may never come back. How can the interviewer choose the best candidate?

Task from probability theory.
I have an idea to sort participants in some way and then to find the probability.
It is the first task of this type and I don't know how to solve them.

Comment: this is known as the Secretary Problem, and can be read about online, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem but it was called the beauty contest problem when I first heard about it.